# AngularJS Inject constant from another file into a factory or another constant

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to make some minor gulp modifications to a project we have that is [I believe] AngularJS based. Currently, we manually have to change API endpoints to point to different environments. I am altering our gulpfile to use gulp-ng-constant so that we can swap environments based on the build command. This is the easy part.

The project was set up to use a config.js file (NOT a config.json) so I have to use gulp-ng-constant to write to a new file (configConst.json --> configConst.js). No problem here either.

What I cannot seem to get working is injecting the constant from the new configConst file into the existing config.js file.

Here is the contents of the compiled configConst.js file:

```
"use strict";
angular.module("apiConstants", [])

.constant("baseEndPoint", "https://testserver.com");
```

And here is the full config.js (I will paraphrase following):

```
'use strict';
angular.module('shell')
    .constant('Config', {
        viewsDir: 'views/',
        componentsDir: 'components/',
        statesDir: 'states/',
        API: {
            protocol: window.location.protocol.split(':')[0],
            //Use the same protocol, host and port as the UI is hosted from bu default
            host: window.location.hostname,
            path: ''
        },
        getEnvironmentUrl: function(apiConstants) {
            console.log(apiConstants);
            var url = window.environmentVariables && window.environmentVariables.getUrl() || '';
            window.environment = window.environmentVariables && window.environmentVariables.getEnvironment();
            return url.indexOf('http') == -1 ? 'http://blah' :
                url;
        },
        getKKServiceUrl: function() {
            var url = window.environmentVariables && window.environmentVariables.getKKUrl();
            return (!url || url.indexOf('{') != -1) ? '/kk' : url;
        },
        landingPageIsActive: function() {
            var isActive = window.environmentVariables && window.environmentVariables.getLanding();
            return isActive == 'true';
        }
    }).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        var checkVersion = function(version) {
            //force browser refresh if api version has been changed 
            if (version && window.buildNumber && window.buildNumber[0] != '#' && !version.startsWith(window.buildNumber)) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        };
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
            return {
                responseError: function(rejection) {
                    checkVersion(rejection.headers('AssemblyVersion'));
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                },
                response: function(response) {
                    checkVersion(response.headers('AssemblyVersion'));
                    var hash = response.headers('PermissionsHash');
                    if (hash) {
                        //debugger;
                        if (window.permissionsHash && window.permissionsHash != hash) {
                            //TODO: update permission service to work with new roles / permissions without refresh
                            //console.log(response.headers('PermissionsList'));
                            //window.location.reload();
                        }
                        if (!window.permissionsHash) {
                            window.permissionsHash = hash;
                        }
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            };
        }]);
    }])
    .config(['componentFactoryProvider', '$resourceProvider', function(componentFactoryProvider, $resourceProvider) {
        componentFactoryProvider.setViewPath(function(componentSnakeName) {
            return 'components/' + componentSnakeName + '/' + componentSnakeName + '.html';
        });
        $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
    }]).value('cgBusyTemplateName', 'views/angular-busy/default-spinner.html').factory('BaseUrl', function(Config) {
        return Config.API.protocol + '://' + Config.API.host + ':' + Config.API.port + '/';
    }).factory('APIBaseUrl', ['apiConstants', 'Config', function(apiConstants, Config) {
        return Config.getEnvironmentUrl(apiConstants);
    }]).factory('KKUrl', ['Config', function(Config) {
        return Config.getKKServiceUrl();
    }]).config(['$breadcrumbProvider', function($breadcrumbProvider) {
        $breadcrumbProvider.setOptions({
            templateUrl: 'components/bread-crumbs/bread-crumb-template.html',
            includeAbstract: true
        });
    }]).config([
        'cfpLoadingBarProvider',
        function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
            cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = false;
        }
    ])
    .config(['$authProvider', '$injector', 'APIBaseUrlProvider', '$httpProvider', 'permissionServiceProvider', 'LanguageProvider', 'Config', 'growlProvider', 'PermissionProvider',
        function($authProvider, $injector, APIBaseUrlProvider, $httpProvider, permissionServiceProvider, LanguageProvider, Config, growlProvider, PermissionProvider) {

            var permissionService = permissionServiceProvider.$get(),
                apiUrl = APIBaseUrlProvider.$get(),
                permissionProvider = PermissionProvider;
            var injector = angular.injector(['ng']),
                _q = injector.get('$q');

            permissionProvider.defineDefaultValidationFunction(function(e, role) {
                var deferred = _q.defer();
                permissionService.hasOneRoleDefer(role).then(function(result) {
                    if (result) {
                        deferred.resolve();
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject();
                    }
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            });

            $authProvider.configure({
                apiUrl: apiUrl,
                emailSignInPath: Config.getKKServiceUrl() + '/Auth',
                emailRegistrationPath: Config.getKKServiceUrl() + '/user/add',
                storage: 'localStorage',
                passwordResetPath: Config.getKKServiceUrl() + '/user/forgot',
                handleLoginResponse: function(resp, status, headers) {
                    permissionService.setSSID(headers('ss-id'));
                    permissionService.setPID(headers('ss-pid'));

                    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = resp.user.baseAuthHeader;

                    permissionService.setUser(resp.user);
                    permissionService.setHomeBreadCrumb();
                    var LanguageFactory = LanguageProvider.$get();
                    LanguageFactory.setCurrent((resp.user.language || '').toLowerCase());
                    return resp.data;
                }
            });
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
                return {
                    request: function(config) {
                        if (config.url.startsWith(apiUrl)) {
                            config.url += '?ss-id=' + permissionService.getSSID() + '&ss-pid=' + permissionService.getPID();
                        }
                        return config;
                    }
                };
            });
            $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
            growlProvider.globalDisableIcons(true);
            growlProvider.globalDisableCountDown(true);
            growlProvider.onlyUniqueMessages(false);
            growlProvider.globalTimeToLive({ success: 5000, error: 5000, warning: 5000, info: 5000 });
        }
    ])
    .config(['uiMask.ConfigProvider', function(uiMaskConfigProvider) {
        uiMaskConfigProvider.clearOnBlur(false);
        uiMaskConfigProvider.allowInvalidValue(true);
    }]);
```

I want to inject the apiConstants into the factory for the APIBaseUrl. This factory calls the Config.getEnvironmentUrl function. I would like to pass the apiConstants into that function, which I can then use to build the final API endpoint URL (where http://blah currently is).

Currently, when serving the app using the included code, the console.log(apiConstants) line returns 'undefined'. If I change it to inject [apiConstants] in the angular.module... line, the browser then complains about the componentFactoryProvider being an unknown provider. I had also thought that I could inject the apiConstants directly into the Config constant, but nothing I tried gave any better progress. Not being well versed at all in Angular and not knowing the correct terms to search for, I'm not sure if I am taking the correct approach or not. How can I inject the constant from the configConst.js file into the config.js file?

Comment: It is not possible to inject other services (including constants) into a constant. For more information, see [AngularJS $provide Service API Reference - constant](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant).

Comment: See also, [AngularJS Developer Guide - Using Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-dependency-injection).